# Как запустить приложение из PDF документа?

Tags: pdf

Читал я пост про устройство pdf и автор писал про такую команду /Launch. С её помощью можно запустить приложение. К сожалению подробного описания не было. Вас прошу рассказать подробнее об этой команде или других вариантах запуска приложения из pdf. Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Имеется ввиду какой-то внедрённый исполняемый код?

Comment: Ну читали, и что? Это ни о чём не говорит - ни вопроса, ни кода, ни примера - НИ ЧЕ ГО. Ну что за люди сюда приходят, поболтать, али зачем? Вы хотя бы ознакомились с правилами нашего сайта в http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking ? Или думаете что на ваш крючок авось кто и клюнет? Прочитайте правила, поймите как и что здесь спрашивают, здесь не пишут ответы на двухстрочный вопрос, тем более не уделяют им вообще внимания.

Comment: Спецификацию вы уже читали?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov [Вопрос не обязан содержать код](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3851/23044). Если вопрос полезен и его можно в две строчки выразить, то его [следует в две строчки выразить, а не разводить тень на плетень](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044). Тема годами обсуждается: [Работа за автора](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/231/23044)